# Why other model name treated as field name in filter in django during joining two table?

Tags: python, sql, django, model

I am new at django.I stuck in a strange problem is that during joining two table foreign model name is treated as field name even i am using __ underscore and i am getting error.
This is my two model :-

````
 class TD_FD(models.Model):
   id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True,db_index=True)
   identity=models.CharField(max_length=25,unique=True,db_index=True)
   del_status=models.CharField(max_length=6,default='na',db_index=True)
   status=models.CharField(max_length=16,db_index=True)
   primary_id=models.ForeignKey('all_scheme',to_field='identity',
   db_column='primary_id'
   ,on_delete=models.PROTECT,max_length=25,
   db_index=True)
   
   def __str__(self):
     return self

 class all_scheme(models.Model):
   id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True,db_index=True)
   identity=models.CharField(max_length=25,unique=True,db_index=True)
   del_status=models.CharField(max_length=6,default='na',db_index=True)
   status=models.CharField(max_length=16,db_index=True)
   scheme_name=models.CharField(max_length=150,db_index=True)
   branch_id=models.CharField(max_length=25,db_index=True)
   
   def __str__(self):
     return self

    ```
This is my query
`deposit_data=TD_FD.objects.filter(all_scheme__branch_id=branch_id).values()`
But .filter('all_scheme__branch_id' treated as field name.Why?
````

Answer (score 0):

Model `TD_FD` does not have anything while calling `all_scheme`. You can try calling that though:

```
deposit_data=TD_FD.objects.filter(primary_id__branch_id=branch_id).values()
```

Firstfully you have to specify field or relation. Since your `TD_FD` has a `ForeignKey` to `all_scheme` that you named `primary_id`, then you have to use that name. But filtering in that way seems pointless, because it will ALWAYS be one object, because it's `ForeignKey` (`ManyToOne` relationship).

Readm more about [Django's relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/).

Comment: NixonSparrow@Thank you bro!!.But i have need your help.How can i get both table matching data?

Comment: For more please read docs, because it's a lot to explain and your approach so far is not good at all.